# How do I install Ubuntu through virtual box?

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning, virtualbox

I have set up Ubuntu on virtual box. I have reached the stage where it says install or try Ubuntu. When I press try, it takes me through a series of steps that I am not sure of, for example , partitions. I do not know which options to select.

Answer (score 1):

When you reach the 'Installation type' screen, you should choose the first option which is usually the simplest. Seeing as you're in a VM, you shouldn't have any problems with other OSes or partitions.

Just choose the 1st option here:
[image: choose 1st option]

Comment: I am running virtualbox on Win 8. I really don't want to wipe out my disk.

Comment: @AsherM That's fine, seeing as it's a VM. It will only erase the **virtual** disk, not your actual Windows 8 disk

Answer (score 0):

just load the setup disc or iso or whatever you use and complete setup! when it says erase disk and install ubuntu dont worry about your real computer just click it and its installed automatically :)